# TComboEdit component

Tags: delphi, components

I would like to create a Delphi component which can have the style of `TComboBox` or `TEdit`. If I set the style as `stCombo` I would like to see a `TComboBox` and if I set to `stEdit` then I would like to see the component as a `TEdit`.

**The main reason of this component will be to change the look of `TComboBox` when is `ReadOnly` to an colored `TEdit`. 
Also, when is styled as `stEdit`, I would like to add some features to `TEdit`.**

I've tried to descend the component from `TCustomPanel`, `TCustomComboBox` or even `TWinControl`.

```
unit ComboEdit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.DateUtils,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, VCL.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.Themes, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TStyle = (stCombo, stEdit);

  [ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TComboEdit = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FPanel: TPanel;
    FCombo: TComboBox;
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FStyle: TStyle;
    procedure SetStyle(const Value: TStyle);
  protected

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Style: TStyle read FStyle write SetStyle;
  end;

implementation

constructor TComboEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Width:= 145;
  Height:= 21;

  FPanel:= TPanel.Create(AOwner);
  FPanel.Parent:= Self;
  FPanel.Top:= 0;
  FPanel.Left:= 0;
  FPanel.Width:= 145;
  FPanel.Height:= 21;

  FCombo:= TComboBox.Create(AOwner);
  FCombo.Parent:= FPanel;
  FCombo.Top:= 0;
  FCombo.Left:= 0;
  FCombo.Width:= 145;
  FCombo.Height:= 21;

  FEdit:= TEdit.Create(AOwner);
  FEdit.Parent:= FPanel;
  FEdit.Top:= 0;
  FEdit.Left:= 0;
  FEdit.Width:= 145;
  FEdit.Height:= 21;
  FEdit.Visible:= False;

  FStyle:= stCombo;
end;

destructor TComboEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FPanel);
  FreeAndNil(FCombo);
  FreeAndNil(FEdit);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TComboEdit.SetStyle;
begin
  if Value <> FStyle then
    begin
      FStyle:= Value;

      case FStyle of
        stCombo:
          begin
            FCombo.Visible:= True;
            FEdit.Visible:= False;
          end;
        stEdit:
          begin
            FCombo.Visible:= False;
            FEdit.Visible:= True;
          end;
      end;

      Invalidate;
    end;
end;

end.
```

If I do like this I get some nasty errors and I don't like the fact that editors can be selected inside of `Panel`.

PS: I'm aware about `csSimple` style from `TComboBox` but it looks different than `TEdit` (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I succeed to do it by creating **compound component** as indicated on this [link](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+9+Writing+Delphi+Components/Creating+Compound+Components/)

```
  [ComponentPlatformsAttribute(pidWin32 or pidWin64)]
  TComboEdit = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FCombo: TComboBox;
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FReadOnly: Boolean;
    FStyle: TStyle;
    procedure SetReadOnly(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetStyle(const Value: TStyle);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Combo: TComboBox read FCombo;
    property Edit: TEdit read FEdit;
    property ReadOnly: Boolean read FReadOnly write SetReadOnly default False;
    property Style: TStyle read FStyle write SetStyle default stCombo;
    property Align;
    property Font;
    property ParentFont;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyPress;
    property OnKeyUp;
  end;

constructor TComboEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FReadOnly:= False;
  FStyle:= stCombo;

  Width:= 145;
  Height:= 21;

  FCombo:= TComboBox.Create(Self);
  FCombo.Parent:= Self;
  FCombo.Align:= alClient;
  FCombo.Name:= 'ComboBox';
  FCombo.SetSubComponent(True); //<--- here is the trick

  FEdit:= TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Parent:= Self;
  FEdit.Visible:= False;
  FEdit.Align:= alClient;
  FEdit.Name:= 'Edit';
  FEdit.SetSubComponent(True); //<--- here is the trick
end;
```

Comment: If you do this, you might want to have a look at ccpack https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccpack/